# Database code crashes on every android API but 4.1

Tags: android, sql, database, android-sqlite

I have some code which is about copying a filled database into a sqlite database in android.

I have tested all my codes with android API version 4.1. But now all other versions crash when I'm trying to take a query from db. Here is the code of the dbHelper :

```
package com.rasta.ghavanin;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

    public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    //The Androids default system path of your application database.
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.rasta.ghavanin/databases/";

    private static String DB_NAME;
    private static String COLUMN_ID_NAME = "_id";
    private static String COLUMN_DESC_NAME = "Description";

    private SQLiteDatabase DataBase; 

    private final Context myContext;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
     * @param context
     */
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context , String DBName) {

        super(context, DBName, null, 1);
        DB_NAME = DBName;
        this.myContext = context;
    }   

    /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

        //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
        //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try 
        {
            copyDataBase();
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    // this method simply open the database
    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        DataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

            if(DataBase != null)
                DataBase.close();

            super.close();

    }

    public String getLaw(int lawID)
    {
        String[] columnNames = { COLUMN_ID_NAME, COLUMN_DESC_NAME};
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query("Laws", columnNames, COLUMN_ID_NAME + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(lawID) }, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null)
        {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(1);
        }
        else
        {
            return "salam :D";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    // Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the database.
    // You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so it'd be easy
    // to you to create adapters for your views.

}
```

here is the logcat , all of it :D

```
01-06 15:10:39.554: D/dalvikvm(562): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
01-06 15:10:40.254: I/dalvikvm(562): Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 8...
01-06 15:10:42.214: D/gralloc_goldfish(562): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
01-06 15:10:46.974: D/dalvikvm(562): GC_CONCURRENT freed 160K, 3% free 10163K/10439K, paused 7ms+8ms
01-06 15:10:47.304: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(562): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: Laws, db=/data/data/com.rasta.ghavanin/databases/Constitution
01-06 15:10:47.316: D/AndroidRuntime(562): Shutting down VM
01-06 15:10:47.324: W/dalvikvm(562): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
01-06 15:10:47.384: E/AndroidRuntime(562): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-06 15:10:47.384: E/AndroidRuntime(562): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rasta.ghavanin/com.rasta.ghavanin.ViewActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Laws: , while compiling: SELECT _id, Description FROM Laws WHERE _id=?
01-06 15:10:47.384: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
01-06 15:10:47.384: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
01-06 15:10:47.384: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
01-06 15:10:47.384: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
01-06 15:10:47.384: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-06 15:10:47.384: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-06 15:10:47.384: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
01-06 15:10:47.384: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-06 15:10:47.384: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-06 15:10:47.384: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-06 15:10:47.384: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-06 15:10:47.384: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-06 15:10:47.384: E/AndroidRuntime(562): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Laws: , while compiling: SELECT _id, Description FROM Laws WHERE _id=?
01-06 15:10:47.384: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
01-06 15:10:47.384: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
01-06 15:10:47.384: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:143)
01-06 15:10:47.384: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:361)
01-06 15:10:47.384: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:127)
01-06 15:10:47.384: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:94)
01-06 15:10:47.384: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:53)
01-06 15:10:47.384: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
01-06 15:10:47.384: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1564)
01-06 15:10:47.384: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1449)
01-06 15:10:47.384: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1405)
01-06 15:10:47.384: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1523)
01-06 15:10:47.384: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at com.rasta.ghavanin.DatabaseHelper.getLaw(DatabaseHelper.java:111)
01-06 15:10:47.384: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at com.rasta.ghavanin.ViewActivity.updateDescription(ViewActivity.java:110)
01-06 15:10:47.384: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at com.rasta.ghavanin.ViewActivity.onCreate(ViewActivity.java:82)
01-06 15:10:47.384: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
01-06 15:10:47.384: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
01-06 15:10:47.384: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
01-06 15:10:47.384: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  ... 11 more
01-06 15:10:50.554: I/Process(562): Sending signal. PID: 562 SIG: 9
```

Comment: and the error would be? Do you have a logcat message for it? Are you sure its not as simple as failing to create the db on other devices. Because you did something different on your test device

Comment: im using AVD for testing.

Comment: and yes i forgot to tell. logcat says somting about not finding the table that im refering in query (Laws).

Comment: i assume that there is problem in copying method. thats why there is no table matching Laws, but i cant figure it out what it may be.

Comment: you should paste your log cat output. That'd make it ton easier for people to answer you.

Answer (score 0):

to get the database path you should really be using something like

```
String myPath = myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getAbsolutePath();
```

instead of the ways you've done `DB_PATH + DB_NAME`

There are a few places you have done this. Not sure it will fix the issue, but its worth trying. and is better practice either way.

(You have hardcoded DB_PATH as `/data/data/com.rasta.ghavanin/databases/` which isnt ideal)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky to diagnose this one without your table definition, but I can tell you this.
The key error is in this statement:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.rasta.ghavanin/com.rasta.ghavanin.ViewActivity}:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Laws: , while
>   compiling: SELECT _id, Description FROM Laws WHERE _id=?

Note that it says there isn't a `TABLE Laws`. Somehow, that's not getting imported on every emulator you are testing. A few tips.

1. There should only be one location to get the database path, all other functions should reference that. This will avoid any confusion, and make it easier to change later if required.
2. As Doomsknight suggested, you are better off using the absolutePath for this reference.
3. I would try using the [sqlite via adb](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#shellcommands) to see if the database looks right. I suspect that when you do that, the problem will manifest itself.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved.

when you create a database in android it automatically adds a table named android_metadata to the database. now, because I was copying my external database using stream, I was rewriting the whole file, so the android_metadata that is necessary for APIs before 4.1 must be added by hand to the external database.

Comment: how you fix this problem then , please support some code ?